# How to count dates in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like below.

[image]

I want to show count of LicenseEndDate. Like In my slicer I have taken WeekEnding column suppose if I select weekending date like 09/25/2022 then I want show the count of **LicenseEndDate** dates that are ended between 09/18/2022 to 09/25/2022. How to create measure for this. I want to show that count in card visual. I created a measure like below

**License_Expired_Count = COUNT(Trade[LicenseEndDate])**.

But It giving me count of all. That mean the License which are expiring in the feature count also it was showing. But want to show count of license which are expired in the selected period. How create measure for this.

Comment: Your starting date is fixed "09/18/2022"? or do you want last 7 days from the selected WeekEndingDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code, let me know If It works for you.

```
License_Expired_Count =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Trade[LicenseEndDate] ),
    Trade[LicenseEndDate] <= SELECTEDVALUE ( Trade[WeekEndingDate] ),
    Trade[LicenseEndDate]
        > SELECTEDVALUE ( Trade[WeekEndingDate] ) - 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
License_Expired_Count = 
VAR _slt =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Trade[WeekEndingDate] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Trade[LicenseEndDate] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Trade[WeekEndingDate] ),
        DATESBETWEEN ( Trade[LicenseEndDate], _slt - 7, _slt )
    )
```

[check sample file attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mXFAub8gBxUMESq-fO049QJbkhmbtKhR/view?usp=sharing)

[image: result]